# Salesforce Notifications - Bell

Tags: notification, task-notifications, task-recurrence

I open salesforce and i see for example 5 notifications (5 tasks assigned to me). If i click on the bell and then click on one task, do my job and return back to home page, the bell has no notifications, whether i would like to show me 4. I understand this may be the approach Salesforce has done it the same as Facebook and other social networks. But i just ask whether there is possibility to implement somehow the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the standard functionality works with notifications and the bell.

You'd be better off using some sort of "Today's Tasks" component on a home page than relying on the bell.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316467&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Ok Kris, Thank you!